# How to check the health of application gateway in Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk, azure-application-gateway

How to check the health of application gateway using java sdk.
I need to perform a similar operation like below azure cli command using java sdk:

*azure network application-gateway backend-health show "$1" "$2" --json \ | jq -r '.backendAddressPools[].backendHttpSettingsCollection[].servers[] | select(.health == "Healthy") | .address'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to get the health value of your pipeline command via the method `health()` of the class [`ApplicationGatewayBackendHealthServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.network._application_gateway_backend_health_server) of Azure Java SDK, but failed because it seems not to be implemented that I could not get the `ApplicationGatewayBackendHealthServer` Object via a implementing path from the root class `Azure` now.

So I tried to search a related REST API to get the response of command `azure network application-gateway backend-health show <resource-group-name> <applicationgateway-name>` on Azure REST API [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/applicationgateway/get-application-gateway#request-body), but also failed that there is not existing.

I tried to research on source code of `AzureCLI` & other SDK, finally I got the REST APIs as you want from the detail logs `azure.details.log` of `AzureCLI`.

The REST API for your needs is as below for 1st step.

> `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<applicationGateway-name>/backendhealth?api-version=<api-version>`

Doing the `POST` request for the above REST API with header `Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>`, you can get the next dynamic REST API from the response header `location` like below via `GET` request with header `Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>`.

> `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/<region>/operationResults/<objectId, such as f7bfd1fd-e3ea-42f7-9711-44f3229ff877>?api-version=<api-version>`

Here is my sample code.

```
String AUTHORITY = "https://login.windows.net/<tenantId>";
String clientId = "<client-id on management portal(old), or application-id on Azure new portal>";
String clientSecret = "<client-secret-key>";
String subscriptionId = "<subscriptionId>";
String resourceGroupName = "<resource-group-name>";
String appGatewayName = "<applicationgateway-name>";
String apiVersion = "2016-09-01";
// Getting access token
AuthenticationContext context = null;
AuthenticationResult result = null;
ExecutorService service = null;
service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", credential, null);
result = future.get();
String accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
System.out.println(accessToken);
```

Using 1st step REST API:

```
// Get the response header `location` from 1st step REST API
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
String url = String.format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%s/resourceGroups/%s/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/%s/backendhealth?api-version=%s", subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, appGatewayName, apiVersion);
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, "");
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).header("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken).post(body).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
String location = response.header("Location");
System.out.println(location);
```

Using 2nd step dynamic REST API:

```
// Get the response content as the same as the azure-cli command `azure network applicationgateway backend-health show`
Request request2 = new Request.Builder().url(location).header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken).build();
// Notice for the below code, see under the code
Response response2 = client.newCall(request2).execute();
System.out.println(response2.body().string());
```

**Notice:**
***I was able to get the content via `POSTMAN`, but I got the response content `null` for the 2nd step using `OKHttp`/`Apache HttpClient`/`HttpURLConnection` in Java. I don't know what happened & why, even the code implemented in Golang/Jquery works fine. It seems to be caused by the implementation of HTTP protocol stack in Java.***

Meanwhile, if you got some error information about permission for the above  REST APIs, please refer to https://github.com/JamborYao/ArmManagement to solve it.

Hope it helps for you. If you can resolve the 2nd step issue, please share the solution with us, and I will continue to try for solving it.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your complete answer. That's very helpful.

Comment: In java this is happening if you've created a Web App in the azure console. If the app is Native then everything is fine.

Comment: An other think, that I've notice: sometime I get 202 from this endpoint https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/<region>/operationResults/<objectId, such as f7bfd1fd-e3ea-42f7-9711-44f3229ff877>?api-version=<api-version> and because of that I have to retry 2 - 3 time using the Retry-After value, which is not accurate at all, all the time is 10 seconds, but some times I need to perform 3 retries and then I'll get the status of the backend.