# Is there an rest API or a SDK for getting the resource health for application Gateway in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Tried searching for API as well as SDK in microsoft website but didn't get any specific result.
I am trying to create a dashboard for all the availability status of all the application gateway using python and plotly.

This api is not providing the output
GET https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/Subs/resourceGroups/Rsg/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/appgw/Microsoft.ResourceHealth?api-version=2018-01-01

Comment: Can you please include the response you are getting for the Api?

Comment: {
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://northeurope.network.azure.com:30018/4abbce30-6340-4fed-8600-0e9f690ab6a8/133008651933684680/subscriptions/xyz/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/xyz/Microsoft.ResourceHealth?api-version=2018-01-01'."
}

I have replaced the subs , rsg and appgw name with xyz for security reasons.

When I check in azure portal the resource health shows available.

Answer (score 0):

***You can make use of Postman by creating a service principal like below:***

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> New Registration*

Make sure to add the **Api permission** like below:

[image]

**Generate the access token via Postman like below:**

[image]

**To resolve the error, try using **`POST`** method instead of  **`GET`** while calling the query like below:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/{applicationGatewayName}/backendhealth?api-version=2021-08-01
```

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can make use of below PowerShell command as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azapplicationgatewaybackendhealth?view=azps-8.1.0):

```
Get-AzApplicationGatewayBackendHealth
```

**Reference:**

[java - How to check the health of application gateway in Azure by Peter Pan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367621/how-to-check-the-health-of-application-gateway-in-azure)

Comment: Hi Rukmini appreciate the solution but I am not looking for the resources in the backend.
I want to check application gateway health as a resource , reason being is that if Microsoft is having any maintenance or outage I will 
like to know if my application gateway is available.

The option which I am looking for is when we open any application gateway in portal we have a option at the bottom left for Resource health.